# Restore purchases is not working on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, xcode8, itunes-store

Until my update to Xcode 8.0 it was all working fine but after the update I am not able to restore purchases on my iOS app. This is my functions which gets triggered after pressing the restore button.

```
func restorePurchases(){
        print("restore purchase method called")
        if(SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()){
            print("can make purchase")
            SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
            SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
        } else{
            print("can't make purchase")
        }
}
```

The issue is it doesn't even connect to iTunes store. There is no sign in prompt either. Absolutely no callback be it updatedTransactions or restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError or paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished.

More interesting thing is I get the itunes sign in prompt once i press the home button to leave the app but now transaction doesn't succeed as the app is out of focus.

Any one have any ideas how to get it sort?

Comment: are you sure that you are conforming to these delegates SKProductsRequestDelegate , SKPaymentTransactionObserver  ?

Comment: @AbdulWaheed Yes 100%. In fact buying a product is working absolutely fine with successfully returning all the callback.

Comment: did the issue resolved or need code?

Comment: @AbdulWaheed No. Issue is not resolved.

Comment: maybe you are missing something.. watch thihs https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zRrs7O5yjKI

Comment: @AbdulWaheed Please do not post generic comments if have no idea what is going on.

Comment: did you solve this , i have a similar problem with restore not working..??

Comment: @clivedancey Nope. No response from Apple till now. :(